# Finite projective resolution of vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

Let
$k$
be a field and
$V$
a finite-dimensional vector space. Show that
for every natural number
$n$
there is a a finite projective resolution of
$k$
-vector spaces

$0→V_n→V_{n−1}
→ ··· →
V
_2
→
V
_1
→
V
_0
→
V
→
0$
with
$V
_i
\neq 0$ for  all
i
= 1
, . . . , n

Comment: Several concerns: (1) It is considered inappropriate to phrase questions posted here in a way appropriate for assigning homework.  It makes it look as if you're passing on to us a question written by someone besides yourself, with no evidence that you even understood the question, rather than asking your own question about it. (2) Either "for $i=1,\ldots,n$" or "for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$" is standard usage; "for all $i=1,\ldots,n$" is not.  (3) This strange format where you write two characters on one line and then go to the next line doesn't make editing easier.  I've fixed (2) and (3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a resolution is made of short exact sequences. In your case you can start with $V_0=V\oplus k$ and $V_0\to V$ the projection on $V$. The kernel of this map is $k$. Then take $V_1=k\oplus k$ and $V_1\to k$ a projection. The kernel of this map is also $k$, and so on. As a final step you can consider the identity map from $k$ to itself.